# Node.js support of X25519 curve

Tags: node.js, node-crypto

I don't see node crypto having any implementations of X25519 curve. I've checked through `crypto.getCurves()`

Am I looking at something wrong or is Node not supporting this curve yet.
If so, are there any other alternatives to use this curve in node's ECDH?

Thanks

Comment: What was the solution you found for this ?